# the right way in differentiating the android device position

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, compass-geolocation

I'm trying to build a compass android app. I need to indicate the North direction when the device is parallel to the ground and/or when the device is in landscape mode.

I'm not sure that is enough if I lock the screen orientation in AndroidManifest and the I detect the device positions by following the roll values from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` & `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`. Then, I assume that I have to remap the device coordinates by using the `remapCoordinateSystem` function.

Is this all that I need in order to indicate the North direction while the device is in one of that two positions?  Some google search results are talking about Euler angles or quaternions. Do I need to use them? The truth is that I know nothing about them.